# Kubuntu 16.04 installation DVD will not boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, kubuntu, uefi

I built a computer recently and want to install Kubuntu 16.04 onto it. I have downloaded the 64-bit ISO, checked the MD5 sum, and burned it as an ISO image. The computer recognizes the DVD and loads it, and the DVD will begin to boot, except while the system is starting services it locks up (it doesn't always lock up on the same service, though). There is no activity on the DVD drive, and I can't interact with the computer anymore. It just sits there until the computer is reset or turned off. I have tried this also with Kubuntu 14.04 and Mythbuntu 12.04.1, and they all lock up while trying to start services. All of these installation disks have successfully booted in other computers I have.

The motherboard does have UEFI enabled, and I have turned off Secure Boot and Fast Boot. Not that it matters, though, I tried booting it in legacy mode and the same exact thing happened...

I have also tried to add the following kernel parameters:

- `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0`: Graphics appeared to work fine without but just to check I used this anyway. No luck.
- `noninteractive` instead of `maybe-ubiquity` to keep it from launching an X server, but still locks up
- `acpi=off` but then the disc just doesn't boot at all

I have been able to boot openSUSE and Windows 10 installation media on the computer, so it appears to be an Ubuntu problem.

Here are some of the system specs, if it matters:

- CPU: AMD FX-8320E
- Motherboard: ASUS 970 Pro Gaming/Aura
- GPU: GeForce 210
- It also has a Hauppage HVR-1600 installed

Comment: Try this answer and scroll down to "If you are unable to enter a TTY" http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935

Comment: It's not that I can't see anything -- the Kubuntu boot logo pops up and I can hit escape to see the boot process. It just locks up while the install system is booting.

Comment: Like I said in the question, the solutions will probably work for more than the listed problems. Your problem could be fixed by following that section. If it is, I can add it.

Comment: That does the same exact thing as `nomodeset`. I can see the boot screen (stretched), I can't hit escape to see the boot progress, and it locks up after a few seconds and I have to forcibly shut the computer down

Comment: I should also point out that nothing has been installed on this computer yet. I'm still trying to get the installation media to boot.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem was the HVR card that was in the computer. I took it out and it booted just fine.

Hopefully the installed system won't do the same thing.